# Representation of rounding error in floating point arithmetic.

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, floating-point, rounding-error

It is well known that in a Floating point number system:

$$
\mathbb{F}:=\{\pm \beta^{e}(\frac{d_1}{\beta}+\dots +\frac{d_t}{\beta^t}): d_i \in \{0,\dots,\beta-1\},d_1\neq 0, e_{\min}\leq e \leq e_{\max}\} \cup \{0\}
$$

The rounding function $\operatorname{rd}: A \rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ (for $A$ chosen appropriately), satisfies the following property:

$\forall x \in A \ \exists \delta \in R: \quad \operatorname{rd}(x)=x(1+\delta), \quad |\delta|\leq u$

where $u:= \frac{1}{2}\beta^{1-t}$ is the unit roundoff.

I‘ve seen in many texts that the following also holds:

$\forall x \in A \ \exists \delta‘ \in R: \quad \operatorname{rd}(x)=x(1+\delta‘)^{-1}, \quad |\delta‘|\leq u$

But I‘ve never seen a proof. If I naively set: $(1+\delta)=\frac{1}{1+\delta‘} \Rightarrow \delta‘=\frac{-\delta}{1+\delta}$ but for negative $\delta$:

$$
|\delta‘|=\frac{|\delta|}{|1-|\delta||}>|\delta|
$$

So potentially $|\delta‘| >u$. I’d be glad if someone could explain?

Comment: In absence of exact literature, just a few ideas: You have to consider positive and negative $\delta$ and $ \delta‘\,.$ The unit roundoff $u$ will typically be extremely small and so are $|\delta|$ and $| \delta‘|\,.$ Therefore $|\delta|\approx| \delta‘|$ from $\delta‘=\frac{-\delta}{1+\delta}\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, for all $x \in A$ there
exists a unique integer
$e \in [e_\text{min}, e_\text{max}]$ such that
$$
\beta^{e-1} \leqslant |x| < \beta^e,
$$
and then
$$
\beta^{e-1} \leqslant |\operatorname{rd}(x)| \leqslant \beta^e
\ \text{ and }\
|\operatorname{rd}(x) - x| \leqslant \frac{\beta^{e-t}}2,
$$
whence
$$
\left\lvert\frac{\operatorname{rd}(x)}x - 1\right\rvert \leqslant
\frac{\beta^{1-t}}2
\ \text{ and }\
\left\lvert\frac{x}{\operatorname{rd}(x)} - 1\right\rvert \leqslant
\frac{\beta^{1-t}}2,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\operatorname{rd}(x) = x(1 + \delta) = x(1 + \delta')^{-1}
\ \text{ where }\ |\delta| \leqslant \frac{\beta^{1-t}}2
\ \text{ and }\ |\delta'| \leqslant \frac{\beta^{1-t}}2.
$$

Comment: Slight correction: I should probably have explicitly defined:
\begin{gather*}
A = \left[\beta^{e_\text{min} - 1}, \beta^{e_\text{max}}\right)
\cup \{0\} \cup
\left(-\beta^{e_\text{max}}, -\beta^{e_\text{min} - 1}\right], \\
\operatorname{rd}(0) = 0
\ (\text{in which case } \delta = 0 = \delta'),
\end{gather*}
and continued:
$$
\text{"for all } x \in A \smallsetminus\{0\} \ \ldots \text{"}.
$$

Comment: I recommend emphasizing the origin of the term $\beta^{-t}$.

Comment: @CarlChristian I didn't want to add more explanation than the (rather terse) question, but how about something along these lines: "We have $\beta^{-e}|x|,\,\beta^{-e}|\operatorname{rd}(x)|\in[\beta^{-1},1],$ and in base $\beta,$ when rounding to $t$ significant digits, $\beta^{t-e}|\operatorname{rd}(x)|$ is the nearest integer to $\beta^{t-e}|x|,$ subject to whatever convention is used to resolve ties." (Eventually, my answer will probably be deleted, along with the question, but I shall have to edit it anyway, if only in order to correct a typo I've just noticed.)

Comment: As the answer has been accepted, I've limited myself to correcting the error in the typesetting of $\operatorname{rd}(x).$